Looker - Hiding a dashboard column based on selected subtotals
I've built a dashboard in Looker wherein I have a product_category dimension and a product dimension. I've enabled subtotals which in turn allows me to click the subtotal arrow next to my product_category column to expand the relevant products as such:



product_category
product




> product_category_1



> product_category_2




By clicking the arrows next to the name of the product_category, it expands the first column and shows the relevant products in the second column:



product_category
product




^ product_category_1




product_1



product_2



product_3


> product_category_2




Is it possible to hide the second column entirely if none of the product_category subtotals are toggled?
*NOTE: This is for Looker, not Looker Studio
I've been looking for ways to interact with subtotal values using HTML or even the row number in the visualization itself with a table calc, but haven't been able to figure out how to make it so that a column does or doesn't get rendered based on the subtotal of another column being toggled.
